# MATLAB offset surface

Tags: matlab

I want to offset surfaces which have grid points. I have some grid points for my goemetrical problem I can plot it with matlab but I can not offset surfaces.

Thanks for your interest

Aliis

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you want arbitrary 3D plots not on the grid, you can try `delaunay` and `trisurf`.

```
N = 300;
X = randn(N,1);
Y = randn(N,1);
Z = sin(X+Y.^2);
tri = delaunay(X,Y);
trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z);
```